# Test ODBC entry on Unix

Tags: linux, unix, odbc

Does anyone know a way of testing if an odbc entry on the odbc.ini file is configured correctly?

I would like to know if my linux server is able to connect to my SQL Server using an ODBC entry I configured.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using unixODBC as the ODBC driver manager then just do:

```
isql -v mydsn myusername mypassword
```

Answer (score 3):

The most common problem is that the default source build setup is set to `/usr/local/etc`, not `/etc`, so you (as me) may be look at a nice config file but unused.

To verify it, just run

```
# odbc_config --odbcinstini
/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

A simple symbolic link solve it.

Another problem can be a missing library, that you can verify by running the `ldd`. ex:

```
# ldd /opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0 | grep "not found"
        libodbcinst.so.1 => not found
```

In this case, I need to put the libodbcinst.so.1 in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or in any directory in use by `/etc/ld.so.conf`.
If you choose to put in ld directories, do not forget to run `ldconfig` as root after it to update ldd cache file.

Comment: How does one get odbc_config on Ubuntu 16.04, @ton ?

Comment: The odbc_config is provided by the package unixODBC. You can download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/unixodbc/ ... I installed it manually and I don't know if apt package management system provides it.

Comment: Thanks @ton. No, it seems that it's not included in the default package.

Comment: how about odbcinst -j